# name 'event' is not defined not sure why im getting this

Tags: python, events, error-handling, pygame, undefined

class GameState():
def **init**(self):
self.state = 'main_game'

```
def main_game(self):
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # this is where the error comes from
    mouse_state = 1
    pygame.mouse.set_pos(mouse_x,mouse_y + 1)
else:
    mouse_state = 0
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
        snake.yV = 0
        snake.xV = -1
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
        snake.yV = 0
        snake.xV = 1
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
        snake.xV = 0
        snake.yV = -1
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
        snake.xV = 0
        snake.yV = 1

    mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake, FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()))

    screen.fill(GREY)

    snake.update()
    food.update()
    utility.update()
    bombs.update()
    food.draw()
    snake.draw()
    utility.draw()
    bombs.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    button = Button()
    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    utility = Utility()
    bombs = Bombs()


    game_state = GameState()
```

while not done:

```
game_state.main_game()
clock.tick(50)
```

pygame.quit()

This is just the snippit of code i can send the rest if needed the thing i did previously i had it under a game loop but this time im making a class and object so i can make multiple levels in the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` and `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` are both outside of the for loop that defines the "event" variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main_game(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # this is where the error comes from
            mouse_state = 1
            pygame.mouse.set_pos(mouse_x,mouse_y + 1)
        else:
            mouse_state = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                snake.yV = 0
                snake.xV = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                snake.yV = 0
                snake.xV = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                snake.xV = 0
                snake.yV = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                snake.xV = 0
                snake.yV = 1

    mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake, FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()))

    screen.fill(GREY)

    snake.update()
    food.update()
    utility.update()
    bombs.update()
    food.draw()
    snake.draw()
    utility.draw()
    bombs.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    button = Button()
    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    utility = Utility()
    bombs = Bombs()


    game_state = GameState()
```

Your code have indentation problems. Which makes event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and other events outside the loop. You code should have looks like this.